# Curl command working via SSH but not via PHP

Tags: php, curl

On one of Paypal's API documentation pages there is the following command.

```
curl -s --insecure -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: caller_1312486258_biz_api1.gmail.com" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: 1312486294" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: AbtI7HV1xB428VygBUcIhARzxch4AL65.T18CTeylixNNxDZUu0iO87e" -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay -d "{\"actionType\":\"PAY\", \"currencyCode\":\"USD\", \"receiverList\":{\"receiver\":[{\"amount\":\"1.00\",\"email\":\"rec1_1312486368_biz@gmail.com\"}]}, \"returnUrl\":\"http://www.example.com/success.html\", \"cancelUrl\":\"http://www.example.com/failure.html\", \"requestEnvelope\":{\"errorLanguage\":\"en_US\", \"detailLevel\":\"ReturnAll\"}}"
```

Running this command via SSH yields a success response.

I'm try to have this exact command run via PHP CURL, but keep getting an error message that the API credentials are incorrect. Since that is obviously not the case (otherwise the above command would have yielded a similar response) I can't come to any conclusion other than there is something wrong with my code, yet a mistake that has been eluding me for several days now:

```
$baseurl = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay'; 

define('PAYPAL_API_USER', 'caller_1312486258_biz_api1.gmail.com');
define('PAYPAL_API_PWD', '1312486294');
define('PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE', 'AbtI7HV1xB428VygBUcIhARzxch4AL65.T18CTeylixNNxDZUu0iO87e');
define('PAYPAL_API_APPLICATION_ID', 'APP-80W284485P519543T');

$returnurl = "http://www.returnurl.net";
$cancelurl = "http://www.cancelnurl.net";

$data = array(
    "actionType" => "PAY",
    "currencyCode" => "USD",
    "receiverList" => array(
        "receiver" => array(
            array(
                "amount" => "1.00",
                "email" => "rec1_1312486368_biz@gmail.com"
            ),
        )
    ),
    "returnUrl" => $returnurl,
    "cancelUrl" => $cancelurl,
    "requestEnvelope" => array(
        "errorLangauge" => "en_US",
        "detailLevel" => "ReturnAll",
    )
);

$headers = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".PAYPAL_API_USER,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".PAYPAL_API_PWD,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-APPLICATION-ID: ".PAYPAL_API_APPLICATION_ID,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
print_r(curl_exec($ch));
```

Can anyone spot anything wrong with this code?

Once again I must stress that this is strictly a PHP CURL issue, not a Paypal one.

Comment: You shouldn't be including your security keys/passwords.... this is a public forum..

Comment: Darren these are public ones published on a Paypal documentation page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/. I would of course never post my own

Comment: Just looking out my friend :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` instead of `CURLOPT_HEADER`. `CURLOPT_HEADER` is just a flag, which you can use if you want to see the response's headers in output.

source: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php